# Nginx how to have multiple subdirectories all share and use root index/css/js files?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a webserver that requires many sub-directories for projects (which will be constantly added to via sftp), and what I have are directories on my webroot for css, js as well as an index.php file and another php file.

The issue I'm having, which may be a simple one I'm just not well versed with nginx configs, is that I want to be able to place .swf files in subdirectories, and have them all use the same index, css, js, etc. which are at the webroot.

What I have tried so far is:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|ico|php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
}
```

and

```
location ~* /swf/ {
    root /static;
    index index.php;
}
```

For an example: example.swf is placed in /a/aTest/ by itself, and when accessing mysite.com/a/aTest, the file will utilize the index and css placed in webroot at /var/www

I am unsure whether I need to be going the route with try_files, or if setting a separate static/ directory to also hold these files is the right way to do it.

Comment: you could always symlink the root js and css folders in the subdirectory and access them that way.

Comment: I forgot to mention that more sub-directories will be added in the future when new projects are added, so I would need to be creating symlinks for potentially hundreds of these small sub-directories, and create new ones as soon as new ones are created.